# Up/down vote links on ads missing

Tags: bug, status-norepro, design, advertising

See the image below. On hover normally the adverts have up and down vote buttons in the box on the top right, but I've just noticed that they are missing. This is only the case with Chrome (latest), it works fine in IE10 on the same computer. I tested on stackoverflow.com

[image]

Comment: Seems to be working now. Probably an issue my end I guess

Comment: It's a conspiracy.

Comment: I can reproduce [the same problem](http://imgur.com/sck8eIj) at this time... Chrome 28.0.1500.72 m.

Comment: FWIW, it's working ok for me now (same Chrome version).

Comment: Strange. I've noticed this problem few days ago and since that time I've restarted Chrome few times, so maybe I need to cleanup history if there's something cached, I dont't know (but haven't tried yet).

Comment: I can't reproduce this, but if you can - reliably - then please post a new report with as much detail as you can, @TLama

Comment: @Shog9, hm, I can't reproduce it today. But I could see that few days (in a row) ago. Hard to say what was wrong (probably on my side ?) since I did the same as days before in the morning - started a new Chrome instance after the fresh system start (without any browser history cleaning). So my case seems to be closed...